# What song plays in the beginning of Noragami episode 12?

Tags: music, noragami

I'm looking for the song that plays in the very first scene of Noragami episode 12 (first season). I've searched many times but for some reason I can't find it.

The closest thing I could find is the song titled "Yatotan" and while that song is similar, it is not the one I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This is "M28" from *Noragami Aragoto* OST (disc 2, track 15). However, this track *is* only on the [reprint version](http://vgmdb.net/album/56225), *not* the [original version](http://vgmdb.net/album/54799). [Here](https://clyp.it/umojfmhk?token=c567833bb105fdaef6892be509396324) is a 20-second extract from the beginning of the track.